# Can we use the phrase "In its own"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

While searching over internet I am finding phrases like *"in its own **right**"* or *"in its own **terms**"*. I couldn't find the phrase *"in its own"*.

Can we use the phrase *"in its own"* as it is. For example can we say,

> Mathematics, in its own, is ultimately the study of numbers.

Comment: Since I could not submit the question I made it more lengthy.

Comment: Oh, dear! Sorry the system tripped you up; it looks like a perfectly good question to me. ... Once you get it past the nanny you can just take out what's superfluous by editing, as I have just done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*In its own* is not English idiom, but there are similar expressions which are.

- *On its own* may mean either "without the help of anything else" or "without being prompted by anything else"
- *By itself* may mean either "without the help of anything else" or "unaccompanied by anything else"

What you probably want is

- *In itself* or *in and of itself*—these have technical meanings in some philosophical traditions, but in non-technical use mean "considered independently of anything else"

Comment: Thank you for explaining, What are those technical meanings of _in itself_? What does this phrase colloquially mean? And what is the meaning of _in its own_? Is _in its own_ grammatically correct?

Comment: @user31782 As I said at the beginning, *in its own* is not English idiom; it doesn't have any assigned meaning. I gave you the common understanding of *in itself*. The technical meanings belong to the study of philosophy--specifically, Thomist philosophy--and are beyond the scope of this site (and my competence).